# Computing average to Fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, fibonacci

My task is to ask the user how many Fibonacci numbers they want and to print that, then also show the average of those numbers. I made a method to show the Fibonacci numbers in my code below, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to incorporate the average part of the program. Not asking for you to do it for me because this is homework for class, but it would be nice to know where I am supposed to write the average part of the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Clancy_Hw_03_04{
   public static void main (String[] args){
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int number = 0;
       System.out.println ("Enter N: ");
       number = input.nextInt(); 

       System.out.println("\n\nFibonacci series for " + number +" numbers : ");
       for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
          System.out.print(fibonacciLoop(i) +" ");
       }
   }

   public static int fibonacciLoop(int number){
       if(number == 1 || number == 2){
          return 1;
       }
       int fibo1=1, fibo2=1, fibonacci=1;

       for(int i= 3; i<= number; i++){
          fibonacci = fibo1 + fibo2;  
          fibo1 = fibo2;
          fibo2 = fibonacci;

       }
       return fibonacci;  
   }    
}
```

Comment: Store the sum of _n_ fibonacci numbers, then divide by _n_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be easier to solve if you printed the fibonacci numbers from within your function, fibonacciLoop(), and not try to return each successive number and print it from the main loop. Then the sum and average are right at your fingertips.

For instance:

```
public static void main(...) {
  ...
  System.out.println("\n\nFibonacci series for " + number +" numbers : ");
  fibonacciLoop(i);
}
static void fibonacciLoop(int number) {
  int fibo1 = 1, fibo2 = 1, sum = 0, average = 0, fibonacci;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 2 && i <= number; i++) {
    System.out.print("1 ");
    sum += 1;
  }
  for (i = 3; i <= number; i++) {
    fibonacci = fibo1 + fibo2;
    System.out.print(fibonacci + " ");
    fibo1 = fibo2; fibo2 = fibonacci;
    sum += fibonacci;
  }
  System.out.println("  average = " + (float)sum/number)
}
```

Edit: Made sure to convert sum to a float before calculating average

Answer (score 0):

Keep computing the sum and then divide it by number.
You can do something like...

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
      int fibo = fibonacciLoop(i);
      System.out.print(fibo +" ");
      sum += fibo;
}
System.out.println("Average = " + sum/number);
```

I hope this time I got your question right.

Comment: The function is run in a loop, so each time the sum variable is reset

Answer (score 0):

Put another integer in your `main` function, to store the total value:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;
    int sum  = 0; // Add this here
}
```

Then, inside your `fibonacci` function, add to that variable:

```
public static int fibonacciLoop(int number)
{
    if(number == 1 || number == 2)
    {
        sum += 1;
        return 1;
    }
    int fibo1=1, fibo2=1, fibonacci=1;

    for(int i= 3; i<= number; i++)
    {
        fibonacci = fibo1 + fibo2;  
        fibo1 = fibo2;
        fibo2 = fibonacci;

    }
    sum += fibonacci; //Put this here, outisde the loop
    return fibonacci;
}
```

When you want to output the average, simply divide `sum` by `number`:

```
System.out.println("Average is: " + (sum / number));
```